# Retrieving the URL in Django template language

Tags: javascript, django

In a Django template, how could I refer to the URL.  I want to use it in static pages, to avoid having live links to the current page.  Is there a way to do this with the Django template language or do I have to use JavaScript to do it?

I would like to do something like

```
{% if current_url == "/about/" %}
About
{% else %}
<a href='/about/'>About</a>
{% endif %}
```

I'm using it for a simple blog, so there are no views written for those pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume by your reference to 'static pages' you mean generic views. Internally, these use RequestContext, so you have access to the `request` object which is the current HttpRequest. So you can access the current URL with `request.path`.

```
{% if request.path == '/about/' %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Note that this `if` syntax is Django 1.2+ only - if you're using an older version, you have to do:

```
{% ifequal request.path '/about/' %}
...
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't seem to work.  The Django version is 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `current_url` in your example above, you can substitute `request.path` (assuming you've got `django.core.context_processors.request` in play). And it'd have to be `==` not `=` :o)

Comment: I have been trying to add django.core.context_processors.request to the settings files (and a range of related settings), but I still don't get it to work.  I had assumed (wrongly) that it would be really simple to do with Django.

Comment: It is pretty simple to do. Can you paste your settings.py into the question above (or at least the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple) so we can have a look?

Comment: When I first asked the question, I didn't have any TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in my settings file.  I have added:

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with simple template inheritance:

```
# base.html
{% block contactlink %}<a href='/contact/'>Contact</a>{% endblock %}
{% block aboutlink %}<a href='/about/'>About</a>{% endblock %}
  ...

# about.html
{% block aboutlink %}About{% endblock %}

# contact.html
{% block contactlink %}Contact{% endblock %}
```

Of course this only works if you have a separate template for each page, but I'm assuming you do since you said the pages are static. Knowing more about what views you are using (assuming generic view direct_to_template or similar) and your urls.py would help.

Comment: SO syntax highlighting apparently does not like django template syntax mixed with python comments.